# DBIx::Class How do I enable PRAGMA foreign_keys for SQLite?

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbix-class

I want to enable foreign keys support to SQLite3 using DBIx::Class, in order to use cascade on update and on delete. I found this http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI/SQLite.pm in the documentation, but is not very clear on how to use it.

This is how I'm setting the Schema.pm and the connection string in my script.

```
# Schema.pm
package MyApp::Schema;
use base qw/DBIx::Class::Schema/;

use strict;
use warnings;
our $VERSION = '0.00001';

__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces();
__PACKAGE__->load_components(qw/Schema::Versioned/);
__PACKAGE__->upgrade_directory('sql/');

# connection string in script
use MyApp::Schema;
my $schema = MyApp::Schema->connect('dbi:SQLite:db/myapp.db');
```

Thanks,

Comment: How do you currently specify your dsn/user/pass? Could you show that code or that part of the config file? Feel free to change the actual dsn, user and password to "DSN", "USER", "PASSWORD".

Comment: I just added the information to the description. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both

```
my $schema = MyApp::Schema->connect(
    'dbi:SQLite:db/myapp.db',
    undef,
    undef,
    {
        on_connect_do => 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON',
    }
);
```

and

```
my $schema = MyApp::Schema->connect(
    dsn           => 'dbi:SQLite:db/myapp.db',
    on_connect_do => 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON',
);
```

should do the trick.

---

As noted in comments, you can also use

```
on_connect_call => 'use_foreign_keys',
```

instead of

```
on_connect_do => 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON',
```

Comment: Awesome, this example completely showed me how to get it working, just instead of using the on_connect_do, I had to use on_connect_call => 'use_foreign_keys' THANKS!

Comment: That's cause it's suppose to be `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`. Fixed.